# Failure to select correct operator== with MSVC but not gcc/clang for templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, operator-overloading, sfinae

The following example compiles fine using gcc and clang, but fails to compile in MSVC. I would like to know if I have unwittingly stumbled into non-standard territory? If not, which compiler is correct? And is there maybe a workaround?
Minimal example (https://godbolt.org/z/PG35hPGMW):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct Base { 
    Base() = default;
    Base(T) {}
    static constexpr bool isBase = true;
};


template <class U>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<U::isBase, bool> EnableComparisonWithValue(U const *) {
  return false;
}

template <class>
constexpr bool EnableComparisonWithValue(...) {
  return true;
}


template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(Base<T> const &, Base<U> const &) {
    std::cout << "operator==(Base, Base)" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

template <class T, class U,
          std::enable_if_t<EnableComparisonWithValue<U>(nullptr), int> = 0>
bool operator==(Base<T> const &, U const &) {
    std::cout << "operator==(Base, U)" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

template <class U, class T,
          std::enable_if_t<EnableComparisonWithValue<U>(nullptr), int> = 0>
bool operator==(U const &, Base<T> const &) {
    std::cout << "operator==(U, Base)" << std::endl;
    return true;
}


int main() {
    Base<int> b1, b2;
    b1 == 42; // gcc and clang compile, msvc does not
}
```

MSVC throws a compilation error `C2676: binary '==': 'Base<int>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`.
clang and gcc call `operator==(Base, U)` as expected.
Interestingly, the result is the same if I remove all the members in `Base` and just define it as `template <class T> struct Base{};`.

Background: I have another class `template <class T> Derived : Base<T>` which does not contain additional data. I would like to reuse all the `operator==` without having to redefine them again for `Derived`. Without the SFINEA stuff, comparing a `Derived<int>` with an `int` results in an ambiguous operator call, because the bottom two `operator==` definitions deduce `U` as `Derived<int>` (AFAIK correctly). So my idea was do disable them to force the compiler to use `operator==(Base<T> const &, Base<U> const &)`. But then I came upon the above problem.

Also, is there maybe a workaround apart from defining the operators for all combinations of `Base` and `Derived`?

Comment: One way to stop the implicit conversion of `int` to `Derived<int>` is to label the constructor as explicit.

Comment: Nope, that does not change the problem. MSVC still fails to compile the code, while gcc and clang are fine with it. In any case, in the original code it is deliberately not explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised that MSVC doesn't compile your code, that seems to me perfectly correct.

So... not sure... but I suppose that is a MSVC bug.

Anyway... given that you also ask for a workaround... I see that also for MSVC works SFINAE if you enable/disable the return type of the operators, so I propose that you rewrite your operators as follows

```
template <class T, class U>
std::enable_if_t<EnableComparisonWithValue<U>(nullptr), bool> operator==(Base<T> const &, U const &) {
    std::cout << "operator==(Base, U)" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

template <class U, class T>
std::enable_if_t<EnableComparisonWithValue<U>(nullptr), bool> operator==(U const &, Base<T> const &) {
    std::cout << "operator==(U, Base)" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

The following is a full compiling example with also a `Derived` class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct Base { 
    Base() = default;
    Base(T) {}
    static constexpr bool isBase = true;
};

struct Derived : public Base<int>
{ };

template <class U>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<U::isBase, bool> EnableComparisonWithValue(U const *) {
  return false;
}

template <class>
constexpr bool EnableComparisonWithValue(...) {
  return true;
}


template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(Base<T> const &, Base<U> const &) {
    std::cout << "operator==(Base, Base)" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

template <class T, class U>
std::enable_if_t<EnableComparisonWithValue<U>(nullptr), bool> operator==(Base<T> const &, U const &) {
    std::cout << "operator==(Base, U)" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

template <class U, class T>
std::enable_if_t<EnableComparisonWithValue<U>(nullptr), bool> operator==(U const &, Base<T> const &) {
    std::cout << "operator==(U, Base)" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

int main() {
    Base<int> b1, b2;
    Derived d1, d2;
    b1 == b2; // Compiles fine
    b1 == 42; // gcc and clang compile, msvc does not
    d1 == d2;
    d1 == b1;
    b2 == d2;
    d1 == 42;
    42 == d2;
}
```